# How to connect CloudSQL Postgres to Hasura Cloud?

Tags: hasura

1. I started a new Hasura-Cloud project and a new CloudSQL project.
2. I have added the Hasura-Cloud ip-address to the allowed connection addresses on cloudSQL

I have tried the following address but I'm always getting "database not found": `postgres://<db--user>:<db-password>@<db-ip-address>:5432/cloudsql/<connection-name>/<db-name>`

Answer (score 2):

After contacting the Hasura team we found the solution to the correct URL

The correct URL is: `postgres://postgres:<db-password>@<db-id-address>:5432/postgres`

Make sure you add the `Hasura Cloud IP` to the allowed IP addresses on cloudSQL, otherwise the Hasua server get's blocked